# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() というエラーについて

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

PHP、SeleniumWebdriverでスクレイピングをしています。以下のコードを実行した際、
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`というエラーが不定期で起こります。
findsElements()の利用として適切ではないコードの書き方なのでしょうか？

**該当コード**

```
if (count($driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::name('要素の名前'))) === 0) {
```

Comment: エラーとしては「配列じゃないものをforeachに渡してる」なので、取得対象のページ構成次第です。 / 「どんな要素を取得しようとしているのか」が具体的に分からないと、アドバイスも付きづらいと思います。 / エラーやソースコードはピンポイントな行単位で抜き出すのではなく、[他のユーザーも状況を確認できるようなサンプルを含める](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)ことを検討してください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。これに関しては、取得対象のページ構成によって変わるのか疑問です、、、。findElements()は要素がないなら、ないで、falseを返すはずなので。加えて要素の名前などはウェブサイトによって無数に存在するので、findElements()にどのような要素名が渡されても対応できるという認識なのですが、そもそもこのfindElements()内で与えた引数を処理できていないことが問題だと考えているのですが、、、。

Comment: [php-webdriver/tests/functional/RemoteWebDriverFindElementTest.php::testShouldReturnEmptyArrayIfElementsCannotBeFound()](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/tests/functional/RemoteWebDriverFindElementTest.php#L44)を見ますと、`WebDriverBy::name` ではなく `WebDriverBy::cssSelector` を使用しています。また、assertion の内容から、要素がない場合は False ではなく empty array が返る様です。

Comment: `findElements`の中で、「内部処理を実行して中間結果を得る」→「中間結果を確かめもせず`foreach`に渡す」と言う流れになっているようです。PHP WebDriverのコードを書き換える、と言うのが一番確実なように思いますが、それがダメなら「`$driver`がこのような状態になっていることを事前に検出して、その場合には`findElements`は呼ばない」ようにしないといけないかもしれません。「どんな場合にこの事象が発生するか」はもうわかっているのでしょうか。「こんな警告は無視する」と言うのも現実的な一つの選択肢でしょう。

Comment: – metropolisさん、コメントが遅くなり申し訳ありません。丁寧に調査してくださりありがとうございます。自分の認識不足でした。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: – OOPerさん、コメントが遅くなり申し訳ありません。アドバイスありがとうございます。「どんな場合にこの事象が発生するか」はわかっていませんが、現状、エラーが収まり続けているので、様子を見たいと思います。